Asking for follow-up material after basic abstract algebra and linear algebra - an algebraic geometric path
I have finished "A first course in abstract algebra" by John B Fraleigh and "Linear algebra done right" by Sheldon Axler. These books cover everything from ground up for an undergraduate-level text. Now, I want to focus on Algebraic geometry. Some text like "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves" by Qing Liu albeit greatly organized, covers some topic that seems really "out of nowhere". I have found some text like "Algebra" by Serge lang approachable but seems rather "too broad" for algebraic geometry purpose.
I'm looking for both abstract algebra and linear algebra graduate-level material that focuses mainly on algebraic geometry that still looks approachable given my background? What do you recommend?

You might look at some material in M. Artin's Algebra and Miles Reid's algebraic geometry for undergraduates. After that the next serious step is commutative algebra, like Atiyah-Macdonald.

I think Commutative Algebra with a View Towards Algebraic Geometry by David Eisenbud is a good book to read. Then you can probably try R. Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry.
